# Java direct cast vs using a local variable to cast

Tags: java, casting

DISCLAIMER: I'm not sure whether this question is answerable as it currently stands. If it is very difficult to answer or actually impossible, I'll repost a compilable example, but I currently don't have time.

Can someone tell me why this compiles:

```
public void addOutputConnLayer(OutputConnLayer mainOutputConnLayer) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, AbstractPanelController<? extends AbstractPanelModel,
            ? extends AbstractPanelView<? extends AbstractPanelModel>>> entry : subControllers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof OutputConnLayerUser) {
            OutputConnLayerUser tmp = (OutputConnLayerUser)entry.getValue();
            tmp.addOutputConnLayer(mainOutputConnLayer);
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas I get an **"OutputConnLayerUser cannot be resolved to a variable"** error when I don't use a local variable? For example:

```
public void addOutputConnLayer(OutputConnLayer mainOutputConnLayer) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, AbstractPanelController<? extends AbstractPanelModel,
            ? extends AbstractPanelView<? extends AbstractPanelModel>>> entry : subControllers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof OutputConnLayerUser) {
            (OutputConnLayerUser)(entry.getValue()).addOutputConnLayer(mainOutputConnLayer); //<--- this line produces the error
        }
    }
}
```

OutputConnLayerUser is an interface with a single method. It looks as follows:

```
public interface OutputConnLayerUser {

    public void addOutputConnLayer(OutputConnLayer ocl);
}
```

Comment: Wrap it properly `( (OutputConnLayerUser)(entry.getValue()))`.

Comment: Oh my God...    *comments must be at least 15 characters in length*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((OutputConnLayerUser) entry.getValue()).addOutputConnLayer(mainOutputConnLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not casting properly. Missing another parenthesis here

```
public void addOutputConnLayer(OutputConnLayer mainOutputConnLayer) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, AbstractPanelController<? extends AbstractPanelModel,
            ? extends AbstractPanelView<? extends AbstractPanelModel>>> entry : subControllers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof OutputConnLayerUser) {
            **(**(OutputConnLayerUser)(entry.getValue())**)**.addOutputConnLayer(mainOutputConnLayer); //<--- this line produces the error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a proper cast:

```
public void addOutputConnLayer(OutputConnLayer mainOutputConnLayer) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, AbstractPanelController<? extends AbstractPanelModel,
            ? extends AbstractPanelView<? extends AbstractPanelModel>>> entry : subControllers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof OutputConnLayerUser) {
            ((OutputConnLayerUser)(entry.getValue())).addOutputConnLayer(mainOutputConnLayer); //<--- this line produces the error
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the additional brackets in the line with the error. You have to cast first and then call the method.